# Resetting dropdown menus using jQuery in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm working on debugging some software and have found a line of code that doesn't seem to work in IE but works fine in both Firefox and Chrome. Can anyone tell me why? My knowledge of jQuery, Javascript, AJAX, etc. is crude at best but I need to reset some dropdown menus in IE as well as the other browsers.

So there's this (not my code):

```
$('form#requestForm input[name!=add]').val(''); // this works
$('form#requestForm select').val('-1'); // this does not
```

The first line - used to reset other input fields around the dropdown menus - works across all 3 tested browsers, but the second does not in IE.

Can you help me figure out what's up? Thanks.

Doing some research, it seems IE doesn't always behave with jQuery. Worst case scenario, I can try resetting the menus from within the associated JSP, but I'd rather try to fix it here first.

Comment: What's the corresponding HTML look like for that dropdown?

Comment: Maybe you have to specify the first value of the select menu as val, not ''

Comment: @ernie Just a typical `<select name="options">       <%@include file="options/options.jsp" %></select>` which links to a bunch of `<option>` tags.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the -1 index to get a select option is either a hack by the other browsers, or a spec not implemented in IE.  What's the behavior you want?  The dropdown to have no option seleted?

Comment: @ernie The very first option is this: `<option value="">Select</option>`, and it's requested that the menus default to that value. It does as much in FF and Chrome, just not IE.

Comment: I'm confused . . . what's the expected behavior when you use -1?  Do you have an option with that value?

Comment: There isn't, I'm equally confused trying to figure out what the original code writer was thinking here. Setting the -1 to just `''` has no discernible effect on the menu.

Comment: @ernie It seems like the command might just flat out not work in IE, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to select the first item, regardless of its value, simply use a baked in JavaScript property selectedIndex http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp , something like this:

```
$('form#requestForm select').each(function(i, e){
    e.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```